# Отцентрировать текст на изображении

Tags: html, css, центрирование

Привет.
Не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы поверх изображения отцентрировать текст относительно самого изображения, чтобы при ресайзе окна, текст всё так же оставался по-центру изображения.

Делал так:

задавал изображение как `background: cover`, и `div` с текстом центрировал через `margin: 0 auto`. Это работает, но сам фон в итоге при ресайзе снизу обрезается.

а если просто изображение использовать через `img`, а тексту сделать `position: absolute`, то работает, но как тогда текст сделать по-центру?

Comment: Где примеры? Покажите тут то что вам нужно. Как обрезается?

Comment: обязательно нужен пример? мне хотелось увидеть просто ваш вариант решения.

Comment: Например так, в ответе написал. Если что то не то напишите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например:

> Вариант 1.

**Код HTML**

```
<div class="block_flex">    
   <div class="block_flex--image">
        <img src="url image" alt=""> 
        <p>Текст</p>
   </div> 
</div>
```

**Код  CSS**

```
.block_flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.block_flex--image {
    position: relative;
}
.block_flex p {
    font-size: 4em;    
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
}
```

> Вариант 2

**Код HTML:**

```
  <div class="block_flex">  
    <div class="block_flex--image">
      <p>Текст</p>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

**Код CSS:**

```
.block_flex--image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 377px;
    max-width: 483px;
    background: url(image url)no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center; 
} 
.block_flex p {
    font-size: 4em;    
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**Получилось:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: большое спасибо!